# Visulizing data using dc.js and MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor, dc.js

I am building a webapp using [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/). I have a collection of data which stored in [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org) database that I would like to visuliz it using [dc.js](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md). is there any tutorial or course that I can learn how to build charts and diagrams?

Comment: Q: Is there any documentation for the dc.js Javascript visualization library?  A: Yes, starting on the [dc.js Wiki](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/).  Q: Are there any Javascript visualization libraries besides dc.js?  A: Yes, many: http://codecondo.com/6-js-libraries-building-visualized-charts-graphs/

Comment: Q: which is the best visualization libraries that I can use with MongoDB ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For dc.js, you're probably best starting with the examples: https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/tree/master/web/examples

dc can visualize just about anything you can convert to an array-of-records format.

You really just need to do a query that returns an array of records, either in CSV or in JSON format.  Then look at the dc.js examples to see how to read in the CSV or JSON.

The important thing is to come up with a way to export it as a single flat array of records, because although crossfilter is multidimensional, it doesn't do well with nested data.  Instead, you will be using each of the columns or fields as a dimension, and filtering the records based on ranges or values of the dimensions.

Comment: how I can convert a collection from Mongodb to the jc.js

Comment: I'm no Mongo expert, but I added a few hints above.

Comment: reading the examples that you posted, there is another opensource which d3.js,what is the rule of the d3.js for visualizing the data. does it do the retrieving of the data from the file or the database!

Comment: See https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests - toward the end are the "convenience methods" like `.json`, `.csv` etc.